# c++ компилируется с ошибкой. заголовок <iostream>

Tags: c++, компиляция, библиотеки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int n = 2017;
    cout << "You date birth: "<<endl;
    cin >>a;
    cout <<"Your age is  "<< n - a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ошибка компилятора...

> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x29):
> undefined reference to 'st d::cout'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x2e):
> undefined reference to 'st d::basic_ostream<char,
> std::char_traits >& std::operator<< std::char_traits<char
> (std: :basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*)' C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x35):
> undefined reference to 'st d::basic_ostream<char,
> std::char_traits >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits
> (std:: basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&)' C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x3c):
> undefined reference to 'st d::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream&
> (*)(std::ostream&))'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x4a):
> undefined reference to 'st d::cin'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x4f):
> undefined reference to 'st d::istream::operator>>(int&)'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x6b):
> undefined reference to 'st d::cout'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x70):
> undefined reference to 'st d::basic_ostream<char,
> std::char_traits >& std::operator<< std::char_traits<char
> (std: :basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*)' C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x7a):
> undefined reference to 'st d::ostream::operator<<(int)'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x84):
> undefined reference to 'st d::basic_ostream<char,
> std::char_traits >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits
> (std:: basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&)' C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0x8b):
> undefined reference to 'st d::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream&
> (*)(std::ostream&))'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0xad):
> undefined reference to 'st d::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> C:\Users\Gor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccC9WmMU.o:havayi1.cpp:(.text+0xce):
> undefined reference to '`st d::ios_base::Init::Init()' collect2.exe:
> error: ld returned 1 exit status

PS ***havayi1.cpp*** - это файл с кодом

у меня с любым кодом так получается, `<iostream>`

а если использую `<stdio.h>`
то все гладко...

Answer (score 7):

Вангую что компиляция С++ кода делалась при помощи `gcc`/`clang`, которые сами по себе не будут подключать стандартную библиотеку языка С++. Из-за неподключенной стандартной библиотеки и [лезут эти ошибки](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/501ab117d7e22935).

Для компиляции С++ кода следует либо использовать `g++`/`clang++`, либо явно попросить  `gcc`/`clang` подключить стандартную библиотеку языка С++ путем [указания `-lstdc++` в командной строке](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9547ce131918f32c).